# CakePHP - how to use $html->link inside an element

Tags: cakephp

How can I use $html->link from within an element?

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: What version of cakephp? In 1.3 it just works. There is somewhere a parameter to control the passing of helpers to elements in 1.2 as far as I remember.

Comment: In the versions of 1.2 I've used, Helpers are automatically passed into view elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both 1.2 and 1.3,this should work:

```
echo $html->link('linkname',array('controller'=>'somecontroller','action'=>'someaction/somearguments'));
```

**Update**

The html helper has changed a little in version 2.x.An example from the [cook book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link)

```
echo $this->Html->link('Enter', '/pages/home', array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Cakephp has easier ways to work with `html->link`s, definitely you can convert links into buttons.

If you want using bootstrap or some css however for normal links you can use:

```
<?= $this->Html->link ('Sometexthere', ['controller' =>'myController', 'action' =>'myAction']); ?>
```

Comment: It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.